# Which event is the selection of a browser form element?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.2

I have a form element that is designed to collect an email address. When a browser sees a really common name like this, it will pre-fill the element with email addresses that have been used before.  Like this:

```
<input type='text' name='Email' id='Email'>
```

I put the element into a variable for later use. Like this:

```
var $Email = $('#Email');
```

When this element is changed through typing or selecting a browser pre-filled option, I want to test the email address. I currently listen for change and keyup events like this:

```
$Email.change(doSomething);
$Email.keyup(doSomething);
```

This all works perfectly. The problem arises when a user clicks into the form element and the browser drops down a list of previous email addresses that have been used and the user selects one of those email addresses.

The change event isn't triggered because the email still has focus. The keyup isn't triggered because the user hasn't pressed a key.

What is the event that is fired when a user selects options from a browser pre-filled form?

Comment: Try using the `input` event.

Comment: This list of events I am trying is here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: Right, but as you have found out, none of those work. Try `.on('input',function(){...`

Comment: Is `input` a type of event?  I've never heard of it before.

Comment: Yes, it gets triggered any time you input or remove content from an input element in modern browsers. IE9 only partially supports it, it doesn't trigger the event on backspace or cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to disable the ability to use the browser autofill by adding `autofill='off'` to the input element.

You could also have it update when the field loses focus: `$Email.blur(doSomething);`

Comment: Chris, I should not have used the trim function. I edited that. No, I want people to be able to select the autofilled selections. What event occurs when they do select it though? I already works just fine when they leave (blur).

Comment: Ah ok, just making sure.  I removed that from my answer since it's not relevant & you removed it from the question now.  Hmm, well if `.blur()` doesn't work, I'm not sure what would in that case.

Comment: Blur DOES work. But that is when the user loses focus from the element. That's not what happens here. When you select an autofilled option, you don't blur. The element STILL has focus. So, blur doesn't work for me.